# Php include cause navigation to postpone

Tags: php, html, css

On my website i have a contact page, which includes a PHP file. (the php file is a contact formular) Strangly enough this include causes the top navigation, header and also footer to switch a bit. The PHP File does not contain any CSS Style changes. I really cant figure out why this is happening maybe you have an idea.

Heres my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/template_EU.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>LoL StreamGallery</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Templates/stylesheet.css">
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/List/diverse/home_mo.png','Images/List/diverse/requestStream_mo.png','Images/List/diverse/AboutContact_mo.png','Images/List/diverse/Lol_mo.png','Images/List/diverse/fb_mo.png','Images/List/diverse/tw_mo.png')">
<!-- grüner Overhead -->
<div id="overhead">
    <div id="overheadText">
    <!-- Home -->
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/List/diverse/home_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/home.png" alt="Home" name="Home" width="55" height="30"   border="0" id="Home" /></a>    
    <!-- Request Streams -->
    <a href="RequestStream.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('RequestStream','','Images/List/diverse/requestStream_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/requestStream.png" alt=    "RequestStream" name="RequestStream" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="RequestStream" /></a>
    <!-- About&Contact -->
    <a href="AboutContact.php" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('AboutContact','','Images/List/diverse/AboutContact_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/AboutContact.png" alt="About&amp;Contact" name="AboutContact" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="AboutContact" /></a>
    <!-- Play LoL -->
    <a href="http://www.leagueoflegends.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Lol','','Images/List/diverse/Lol_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/Lol.png" alt="Play LeagueofLegends" name="Lol" width="160" height="30" border="0" id="Lol" /></a>
    <!-- Rechtsbündig -->
    <span style="float:right">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Lolstreamgallery" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('FB','','Images/List/diverse/fb_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/fb.png" alt="Facebook" name="FB" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="FB" /></a>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <a href="https://twitter.com/LStreamGallery" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','Images/List/diverse/tw_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/tw.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="Twitter" /></a>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- website Wrapper -->
<div id="website">
    <!-- Header --> 
    <div id="header">
            <p> 
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/logo.png"/></a>
            </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Wrapper -->    
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Anzeige für Streams -->
        <div id="content">
              <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Streamcode" -->
              <p><h1>About us:</h1></p>
              Lol StreamGallery was launched in early 2013 from Jakob Abfalter with the help and ideas of Bernhard Abfalter, Michael Langhammer, Martin Langhammer, Anton Schendel. 
              The website belongs to and was programmed by Jakob Abfalter.
              <p><h1>Media owner:</h1></p>
              <span class="close">
              <p><b>Jakob Abfalter</b></p>
              <p>Uferweg 4</p>
              <p>3341 Ybbsitz</p>
              <p>Austria</p>
              <p>JakobAbfalter@gmail.com</p>
              </span>
              <p><h1>Get in touch with us:</h1></p>
              <span class="close">
              <p>Follow us on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Lolstreamgallery">Facebook</a></p>
              <p>Follow us on <a href="https://twitter.com/LStreamGallery">Twitter</a></p>
              <p>Send us a mail:</p>
              </span>
              <?php
              include("html-contact-form-captcha/html-contact-form.php");
              ?>
              <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
        </div>
        <!-- Menüleiste -->    
        <div id="right">
          <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
              <li><a href="Asia.php" target="sideframe">Asia</a></li>
              <li><a href="NA.php" target="sideframe">NA</a></li>
              <li><a href="EU.php" target="sideframe">EU</a></li>
            </ul>
            <iframe src="EU.php" width="212px" height="980px" name="sideframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Wrapper Ende -->
</div>
<!-- Website Wrapper Ende -->
<!-- Fußzeile -->    
<div id="footer">  
Copyright 2013 © LolStreamGallery - <a href="TermsofUse.html">Terms of Use</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>

<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

What i also found out is, that the PHP Include causes the link in the footer to be bold. Hopefully some of you have an idea, how i can fix this issue.

Edit: Problem Solved - The php file contained some CSS i overread, that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure PHP include causes the link to be bold, the page you include may have CSS on it that is overriding your CSS. You should check your included PHP file for any CSS that may affect links IE

```
a
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Without posting the contents of your included file, we can't really help much further (We'd just be guessing).

Also this question is kinda specific, and may not be constructive as such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
could CSS defaults in the php also overwrite my CSS?
Edit: OK i found it, there really is a bit of CSS in the PHP i just overread. Thx for helping me :)